# Trying to print the first 250 characters of a string but getting ArgumentOutOfRangeExecption" error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, listview, linq-to-entities, asp.net-4.5

I am binding a LINQ result to a ListView and trying to print only the first 250 characters from the "Synopsis" column but when I try to use Substring I get the error:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and length must refer to a location within the string. Parameter name: length

The code causing the error is:

```
<%#:Eval("Synopsis").ToString().Substring(0,250)%>
```

If I remove both the ToString and Substring the error goes away but the entire Synopsis is printed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` exception whenever your start index or length are outside of the range of the string length. In your case I'd say the string is most likely less than 250 characters already. You might instead want something like:

`<%#:Eval("Synopsis").ToString().Length > 250 ? Eval("Synopsis").ToString().Substring(0,250) :  Eval("Synopsis").ToString()%>`

Answer (score 0):

This means the synopsis is less than 250 characters long. This can be easily fixed by checking if the length of the string is greater than 250 and reducing the length of your request to fit. I'm not familiar with LINQ, but here's a solution in pseudo code:

```
var length_of_request;

if length of synopsis < 250 then:
     length_of_request = length of synopsis
else:
     length_of_request = 250
```

Then call `SubString` with `length_of_request` as the second argument.